# How can I save to PDF from Chrome with as good results as Safari?

Tags: pdf, chrome, printing

On macOS, Safari's "Export as PDF..." menu option is fast, and prints to a single page PDF. I'd like to do the same in Chrome.

It seems the recommended way to save a page as a PDF is to "Print.." it, and then choose to output as a PDF, either by using the system dialog, or by opening it in Preview and then saving it from there (see screenshot).

Is there an easy way to print a single page PDF from Chrome? I've tried a couple of extensions which have not worked well, and know there are a ton of others, but don't want to keep installing/trying new extensions.

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with Chrome's built-in print options?

Answer (score 1):

I use this site's plugins in all my browsers. Great for documentation too. Allows you to remove the unnecessary crap out of the pdf before creating it also.

https://www.printfriendly.com/

Comment: Looks good, I'll try it soon!

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Chrome's built-in Print option on macOS for a while now, and I've never had any issue with it:

[image]

What has your experience been?

Comment: What I'd like is a single page PDF, not a typical PDF which is broken up into pages